# How to check that if current user (ID) has posts or not

Tags: users

I have a Custom template. In it i want to check that if the current logged in user has custom posts named (student_form) or not if posts equals true i want to redirect it to some page other wise i want to show him/her a form which i created using wp fronted user.

Following code i wrote but its showing me blank page.

```
     <?php 
     /*
     * Template Name: Form Page
     */
     get_header(); 


     global $current_user=null;
     get_currentuserinfo();

     $args=array(
     'author' => $current_user->ID,
     'post_type' => 'student_form',
     'caller_get_posts'=> 1
     );
     $my_query = null;
     $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
     if( $my_query->have_posts() ) 
     {

     exit( wp_redirect('http://burjhuraira.com/orgibs/dashboard/') );
     }

     else
     {
     echo do_shortcode('[wpuf_form id="414"]');

     }

     wp_reset_query();

     get_footer(); 
     ?>
```

Comment: Please do **not** use flags against your question in case there's no progress.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your redirection must happen before the HTTP headers are sent out.

You can try the following, where we place our logic inside the `template_redirect` hook callback (PHP 5.4+):

```
/**
 * Redirect logged-in users to the admin dashboard 
 * if the have written 'student_form' posts
 * else display [wpuf_form id="414"]
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if( wpse_current_user_has_posts( 'student_form' ) )
    {
        // Redirect to the admin dashboard:
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );  // Edit to your needs!
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        // Note that here you might instead do a redirect to a page containing that shortcode.
        get_header();
        echo do_shortcode( '[wpuf_form id="414"]' );
        get_footer();
        exit();
    }

} );
```

where we use this helper function:

```
/**
 * Check if the current user has written any posts in a given post type
 * 
 * @param string $post_type
 * @return bool
 */    
function wpse_current_user_has_posts( $post_type = 'post' )
{
    $posts = [];
    if( $uid = get_current_user_id() )
    {
        $posts = get_posts( 
            [ 
                'posts_per_page' => 1, 
                'post_type'      => sanitize_key( $post_type ), 
                'author'         => $uid,
                'fields'         => 'ids'
            ]
        );
    }
    return 0 < count( $posts );
}
```

Comment: should i Write both in function.php?

Comment: that should work or better yet create a plugin @AmmarUlHassan

Comment: Actuall iam not that good in WP and my concepts for hooks are also weak so please explain about ur answer

Comment: You could try your `functions.php` file first. I haven't tested the code but hopefully there are no syntax errors. Note that this is for PHP 5.4+. The reason why I choose the `template_redirect` hook is that it happens before the HTTP headers are sent out. @AmmarUlHassan

Comment: Its not working :(

Comment: Please elaborate further: is there a syntax error? logical error? do you use outdated version of PHP?  @AmmarUlHassan

Comment: Please review my edited post(question) above problem is that its not nulling the last logged in user. ever time the if condition is getting true even if the user is not logged in

Comment: I just tested my code and it seems to work as expected. What happens when you try it? Do you need to restrict this to a specific page? Ps: You shouldn't be using `wp_redirect` inside the template file. @AmmarUlHassan